# Checking against an object property in an array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
var array = [];
```

Now, I am creating an object with post requests.

```
var object = {
  property 1: req.body.x;
  property 2: req.body.y
};
```

if the property 1 value(i.e. `req.body.x`) already exists in any of the objects in the array, it should giving a warning.  Else we need to do `array.push(object)`.

How to check for the property 1 value every time with the post request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [array.Find](http://s/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) in order to check if an object exists in the array with the same property.

```js
const arr = [{
  prop1: 'foo', // prop1 of `foo` already in array
}]

// small function so we can avoid code duplication
const existsInArray = (obj) => {
  return arr.find((a) => a.prop1 === obj.prop1)
}

const obj1 = {
  prop1: 'foo',
}

const obj2 = {
  prop1: 'bar',
}

if (existsInArray(obj1)) {
  console.warn('obj1 already in array')
} else {
  arr.push(obj1)
}

if (existsInArray(obj2)) {
  console.warn('obj2 already in array')
} else {
  arr.push(obj2)
}

console.log(arr)
```